# How can I receive FitBit data from my own iOS app?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, fitbit

I know there's a RESTful API for FitBit (https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+API), but I'm interested in incorporating FitBit data directly via BLE into my iOS app.

Doesn't seem this is officially supported, since there aren't API docs for the BLE local protocol.

Anyone have any success doing this, despite the lack of official docs?

Comment: I'd recommend to use LightBlue and try reverse-engeneering.